Having trouble with basic rendering of a full javascript page with playwright to create a PDF
Just trying to do a pretty basic scrape to PDF using Playwright in python.  The coursera pages give me a hard time though.
Not all of the page is rendered for some reason and I only get the basic details without the syllabus (ie: "There are 5 modules in this course..." then a table) for https://www.coursera.org/learn/english-common-interactions-workplace-basic-level
Here's my code, should be straight forward, very basic scrape with some human-like scrolling for good measure.
    def fetch_url_as_pdf(self, url: str):
        """
        Fetch URL and update the instance with PDF and metadata
        """

        with sync_playwright() as p:
            # Start the browser
            browser = p.chromium.launch(
                headless=True,
                args=[
                    "--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled",
                    "--disable-infobars",
                    "--disable-notifications",
                    "--no-default-browser-check",
                    "--no-first-run",
                ],
            )
            logging.info("Setup browser as %s", browser)

            # Setup the context
            context = browser.new_context(
                user_agent=(
                    """Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 """
                    """(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.114 Safari/537.36"""
                ),
                viewport={"width": 1280, "height": 800},
                screen={"width": 1280, "height": 800},
                record_video_dir=DATA_DIR,
            )
            logging.info("Setup context as %s", context)

            # Load the page
            page = context.new_page()
            page.emulate_media(media="screen")
            response = page.goto(
                url,
                wait_until="load",
                timeout=100000,  # Increase timeout to 100 seconds
            )
            logging.info("Fetched page as %s", page)
            page.wait_for_load_state()

            # Scroll the page to the bottom
            self.scroll_page_slowly(page, scroll_pause_time=0.25)

            self._set_metadata(response)
            self.pdf = page.pdf()

            browser.close()

    @staticmethod
    def scroll_page_slowly(page, scroll_pause_time=0.5):
        """Scrolls down the page slowly to simulate human behavior."""
        scroll_height = page.evaluate("document.body.scrollHeight")
        current_position = 0
        while current_position < scroll_height:
            scroll_lines = random.randint(50, 80)
            page.evaluate(f"window.scrollBy(0, {current_position + scroll_lines});")
            current_position += scroll_lines
            sleep(scroll_pause_time)
            scroll_height = page.evaluate("document.body.scrollHeight")

Here's the video resulting from record_video_dir:
Video
I've tried a few different waiting methods including static times, domcontentloaded and load.
